# I am attempting to build a database using sqlite3 via the terminal but I keep getting these errors. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

```
import sqlite3 as lite 
 import sys
 con = None
 try : 
     con = lite.connect('selfdb.db')
     cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT SQLITE_VERSION()')
     data = cur.fetchone()
     print "SQLite version: %s" % data

  File "<stdin>", line 7

    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
 except lite.Error, e :
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    except lite.Error, e :
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In the command line I press enter two times to come out of the indent for the try function but I also get an error. This is similar for except.

Comment: @e4c5 I am using the shell. I want to learn it from the shell. How do I fix this error though?

Comment: @e4c5 I have been doing it by using python files but I would like to have a balanced view though of both utilities.

Answer (score 0):

Is this code just supposed to print the version of SQLite? You have a lot of whitespace errors. Try this:

```
import sqlite3 as lite 
import sys
con = None

con = lite.connect('selfdb.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT SQLITE_VERSION()')
data = cur.fetchone()
print "SQLite version: %s" % data
```